# What is the logic to find out Leonardo number in C programming?

Tags: c

Leonardo number

```
L(x)= {
    1               if x=0
    1               if x=1
    L(x-1)+L(x-2)+1 if x>1
}
```

If x>1, what logic can I apply to find out the Leonardo number?

Comment: `int L(int x){if (x<2) return x; return L(x-1) + L(x-2) + 1;}`

Comment: This is not a site to do your homework for you.

Comment: I am not asking you to do my homework. Just asking the logic

Comment: Well, the first comment did it.

Comment: @EOF-- this will give L(0) = 0, instead of L(0) = 1.

Comment: EOF is right, becaus he's looking for x>1

Comment: @Oswald-- from this viewpoint, there is no need for `if (x < 2) {}` then....

Comment: @DavidBowling If you leave of the -- after the `@USERNAME`, the addressed user *may* actually be notified. On topic: you're right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: @EOF -- funny. I always use a dash there; I'll have to start introducing a space! (Maybe that's why nobody ever listens to me....)

Comment: @DavidBowling Well, that has to awkward. All the time you thought people were ignoring you. Reminds me of when I used to give out my cellphone number incorrectly...

Comment: @EOF Was that [867-5309](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/867-5309/Jenny)?

Comment: @chux Im not *quite* that old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `L(int x)`

If `x` is 0 or 1

`return 1;`

If `x` is greater than 1

`return L(x-1) + L(x-2) + 1;`

What I am doing using `L(x - 1)` is calling the function for the value `x - 1` and the value will be evaluated directly as 1 if it is 0 or 1, otherwise it call again for `(x - 1) - 1` i.e. `x - 2` and the process repeats.

Same is the case for calling `L(x - 2)`.

This is the logic, without the entire code.

For more information on this kind of logic, try searching for Recursion.

Comment: Thanks @akshayk07